# Conectar e pegar um arquivo de uma FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Estou tentando pegar um arquivo de uma FTP, porém não estou conseguindo receber e também não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro, pelo contrario...

Abaixo o código que estou usando:

```
<?php

/* Declaração de variáveis */
$serverHost = 'ftp.teste.com.br';
$serverUser = 'teste';
$serverPass = 'teste';
$arquivoLocal = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\temp';
$diretorioRemoto = '/pub/cre/licenca/';
$arquivoRemoto = 'licencas00003935000121.dat';

/* Faz conexão com o servidor */
if (!$ftp = @ftp_connect($serverHost, 2321)) {
    echo "Erro ao se conectar com o servidor FTP...\n";
}else{
     echo "Sucesso ao se conectar com o servidor FTP...<br>\n";

}

/* Efetua autenticação no servidor */
if (!@ftp_login($ftp, $serverUser, $serverPass)) {
    echo "Erro ao efetuar autenticação no servidor FTP...\n";
    }else{
     echo "Sucesso ao se autenticar com o servidor FTP...<br>\n";

}

/* Definindo o modo passivo ligado */
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
/* Acessando o diretório onde está o arquivo */
if (!@ftp_chdir($ftp, $diretorioRemoto)) {
    echo "Erro! Diretório não existe...\n";
    }else{
     echo "diretorio encontrado...<br>\n";

}
/**
* Copia o arquivo do servidor remoto para o servidor local
* Use FTP_ASCII para arquivos texto
* Use FTP_BINARY para arquivos binários
*/
if (@ftp_get($ftp, $arquivoLocal, $diretorioRemoto, $arquivoRemoto, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Erro ao fazer download do arquivo...\n";
}else{
    echo "sucesso<br>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: O `@` em `@ftp_connect`, `@ftp_login` etc. Serve para ocultar os erros, por isso eles não aparecem.

Comment: tirei todos, agora da essa mensagem de permissão! Já adicionei as permissões e nada!                        
 Warning: ftp_get(C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\temp): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\conectaftp.php on line 36

Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\temp in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\conectaftp.php on line 36

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$local_file = 'temp/arquivo.dat';

$server_file = '/pub/licenca/licencas96668116000172.dat';

$ftp_server="ftp.com.br";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,2321)or die("Erro de conexão com 
$ftp_server");

$ftp_user_name="teste";

$ftp_user_pass="teste";

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die("Não foi possível realizar o Login");

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Não foi possível mudar para o modo passivo");

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {

  echo "Transferência da licença foi executada com sucesso\n";

}
else{

  echo "Verifique e tente novamente\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: E o que mudou? O que estava errado? Como corrigiu? Por que a alteração resolveu o problema? Poderia completar a resposta com essas informações?